# Resize image inside modal window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I've created a modal for a payments page inside my web application and want to show the branding of the payment provider; Stripe.

By default the image is 1950x927. I can manually change this using `style` however this doesn't make the image size truly dynamic; i.e it might look fine on desktop but still extends over the modal on mobile.

Desktop:

[image: Stripe image - desktop]

Mobile:

[image: Stripe image - mobile]

How can I get the image size to load responsively with the modal?

Below is the code on my page:

```
<!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">How can you know your payment is secure?</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="{{ asset('img/stripe.png') }}" style="height:250px;">
        <p>Stripe has been audited by a PCI-certified auditor and is certified to <a href="http://www.visa.com/splisting/searchGrsp.do?companyNameCriteria=stripe" target="_blank">PCI Service Provider Level 1</a>. This is the most stringent level of certification available in the payments industry. To accomplish this, they make use of best-in-class security tools and practices to maintain a high level of security at Stripe.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you try to add `class="img-responsive"` to your image and eventually the `width="100%"` and `height="auto"` ?  Additionally it is bad practice to use such a large image an then scaling it inline or with a css class. You shoul rezize the image with an image editor software first. But this is up to you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition
>   of the .img-responsive class.

For more information you can read [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images)

Try this:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('img/stripe.png') }}" style="max-height:250px;">
```

Comment: This works too. I didn't even realise Bootstrap had an `img-responsive` class. I like this approach as it doesn't involve manually setting `style`.

Comment: It works as well for Bootstrap 4 with `class="img-fluid"`

Answer (score 9):

Images in Bootstrap can be made responsive by just adding a class to img tag.

For Bootstrap 3: Use `.img-responsive`

```
<img class="img-resposive" src="{{ asset('img/stripe.png') }}" >
```

For Bootstrap 4: Use `img-fluid` as the `img-responsive` doesn't exist anymore in v4.

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('img/stripe.png') }}" >
```

Comment: img-fluid does the trick for me. `[+1]`

Answer (score 5):

Just add the class **.img-responsive** to your image, like:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/stripe.png') }}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

Checkout this page to learn more about responsive images and video - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-images.php

Answer (score 3):

`<img src="{{ asset('img/stripe.png') }}" style="height:250px; width: 100%;">`

Adding `width: 100%;` fits your image inside the `div` correctly.

It is very useful in page size change as it keep the ratio between height and width changed according to the width of `div`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set a max width on the image tag.

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/stripe.png') }}" style="height:250px;max-width: 100%;">
```

Comment: Works a charm! Thanks! I searched high and low for a solution, and couldn't find anything from the searches I ran.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="~/images/coming-soon.svg" height="310px" class="img-fluid" />
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your answer to give some explanation of how this works?  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61951339/3744182) from [NSR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10789684/nsr) already mentions using `img-fluid` so it would be helpful if you could also explain how your answer extends that previous answer.  Thanks!  -[From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/33418853).